# What are the all unlocks in Sentinels of the Multiverse and how to achieve them?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Patch 1.1 added some onlock and scattered across various forums came reports how to unlock this or that. I'm wondering what would be the full (known) list of unlocks along with the way to achieve them (if known).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from here: http://sentinelsdigital.com/forum.html#!/?unlocks

- G.I. Bunker: Use all three of Bunker's modes in one game
- Young Legacy: While on Mars, have damage from Baron Blade incapacitate Legacy
- Super-Scientific Tachyon: Put 5 bursts into the trash in a single turn
- Rook City Wraith: Use two Infrared Eyepieces in a single turn
- Mad Bomber Blade: After defeating Baron Blade at least once, fight Dawn and destroy Citizens Blood, Sweat, and Tears in one round
- Cosmic Omnitron: After defeating Omnitron at least once, fight Voss and destroy both of his ships in one round

**Tips:**

- Legacy: Lead from the Front isn't necessary, but can make this a lot easier.
- Blade & Omnitron: The order that the Citizens/Ships are destroyed in doesn't matter, as long as they destroyed in a single round. Infrared Eyepiece(s) or Suggestion can be very helpful for getting the required targets out at the same time. Getting the required targets under Savage Mana, then using that to destroy them does count for the trigger. The prevously required victory does not need to be done immediately prior to the triggering battle.