# When unlocking a Variant card that requires two games, do I have to play them consequtively?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

In the *Sentinels of the Multiverse* video game, there are [a number of Variant cards](http://www.sentinelsdigital.com/variants.html) to unlock. Some of them require more than one game to be played. For instance, "The Eternal Haka" requires the following:

> Win a game where Haka is the only non-incapacitated hero. Then, defeat any villain in The Final Wasteland, playing each “Haka of” card at least once each. Again, Haka must be the only non-incapacitated hero.

Do I have to play the two games consecutively? In this instance, can I win a game where Haka is the only one left, then play 10 games, then win with the final criteria? Or do I have to immediately win the second game after the first (thus possibly spoiling my chance to win the card if I fail to do so)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the all unlocks in Sentinels of the Multiverse and how to achieve them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202802/what-are-the-all-unlocks-in-sentinels-of-the-multiverse-and-how-to-achieve-them)

Comment: This is answered in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202802/what-are-the-all-unlocks-in-sentinels-of-the-multiverse-and-how-to-achieve-them
Specifically, at the end of "Tips":
The prevously required victory does not need to be done immediately prior to the triggering battle.

Comment: @MikeR Being buried in the answer doesn't feel like a duplicate question to me. Is it possible that two different questions have the same answer?

Comment: @Thunderforge, most definetly. In fact, the answer should not be taken into account, when choosing to VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time and found out that, no it is not necessary. As a test, I decided to try and unlock Freedom Six Tachyon:

> Lose a game to Iron Legacy with regular Tachyon on the team. Then, defeat any villain with regular Tachyon and without a Legacy on the team. Fleet of Foot must be played at least 5 times.

To do this, I lost a game with Iron Legacy (not hard to do; just keep passing), then played a few games with Tachyon. Then I played one where I played Fleet of Foot 5 times and the variant unlocked.

I have no reason to think that it works differently for other variant unlocks (I'll unlock others to confirm), but so no, you do not have to play a game right away.

Comment: It's really logical since for the Freedom Six, most of them requires a hero to be incapacited and be the only one to be incapacited. You don't have to lose to Iron Legacy every two runs; it would be to annoying.